# Debugging of WinRT's background networking

Tags: c#, debugging, sockets, background, windows-runtime

I've made a project than uses tcp sockets connectivity (own closed protocol), added background connectivity with Network Trigger API, as described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28999) (starting from page 17) - StreamSocket control channel registration block, and IBackgroundTask class, that should be fired each time socket receives something.

Have tried everything to debug the code in background task, with no use:

- closing the visible app with a gesture
- lock the screen
- tried to load some other heavy application, to make windows suspend my app

All these have not helped me to make background task run (and debug) during socket message. What am I doing wrong? Should I have to get the separate suspendable device, like a WinRT tablet, to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

By default referenced projects are not added to the main one. This is not so obvious as it may seem, and that's why I spent almost a week to find out this. <strike>So the clue is: **check reference projects accessibility**.</strike>

Upd:

There are some more things to deal with, as I've found out during development. Some of them are not as clear as they need to. Here is a list of what I did:

1. Add background project to main project's references (right click on references node in solution browser).
2. Check if main project manifest contains right declaration (background task w/control channel, right background entry point name with full package, $targetnametoken$.exe as executable)
3. A thing that leads from #1: all the entities you plan to use within background, should be put into separate project in solution. This project is then referenced by both main and background projects.
4. Be aware of BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync() to be called before registering ControlChannelTrigger
5. A key thing I've found just in one small comment in a sample project:

```
            // IMPORTANT: When using winRT based transports such as StreamWebSocket with the ControlChannelTrigger, 
            // we have to use the raw async pattern for handling reads instead of the await model.  
            // Using the raw async pattern allows Windows to synchronize the PushNotification task's  
            // IBackgroundTask::Run method with the return of the receive  completion callback.  
            // The Run method is invoked after the completion callback returns. This ensures that the app has 
            // received the data/errors before the Run method is invoked. 
            // It is important to note that the app has to post another read before it returns control from the completion callback. 
            // It is also important to note that the DataReader is not directly used with the  
            // StreamWebSocket transport since that breaks the synchronization described above. 
            // It is not supported to use DataReader's LoadAsync method directly on top of the transport. Instead, 
            // the IBuffer returned by the transport's  ReadAsync method can be later passed to DataReader::FromBuffer() 
            // for further processing.
```

More info here - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8/sourcecode?fileId=57961&pathId=2085431229

If you did all things properly, the debugging of background tasks is straightforward. Just put the breakpoint and go on, nevermind of main project is running or suspended.

**ps** - If the project is suspended, be aware of calling UI thread (especially awaited things) - they won't run until app is running, and will wait.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to "check reference projects accessibility"? Because I have the same problem right now.